# Why should UNNEST be provided only after "from" clause

Tags: google-bigquery

Why should UNNEST be provided only after "from" clause

E.g.
This query fails with an error as "Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST at [2:8]"

> WITH groc as (select ["ram"] as list)
> SELECT UNNEST(list) FROM  groc

While

This one runs successfully

> WITH groc as (select ["ram"] as list)
> SELECT (select * from UNNEST(list)) FROM  groc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UNNEST is a table valued function and usually is used for arrays construction, flattening, filtering, etc. - thus kind of returns a table with rows, etc. so you need to use it with this in mind. You cannot just `select table` - rather your should `select from table`

Meantime, the "correct" version of your second query should be as below, so it runs successfully not only for array with one element, but with many elements

```
WITH groc as (
  select ["ram", "abc", "xyz"] as list
) 
SELECT array(select * from UNNEST(list)) list
FROM groc
```

in this case result is

[image]

which really makes sense only if you want to transform original array somehow or filter out some elements - otherwise it just returns the very same array - for example

```
WITH groc as (
  select ["ram", "abc", "xyz"] as list
) 
SELECT array(select item || "2" from UNNEST(list) item where item != "abc") list
FROM groc
```

with output

[image]

As of your first query, usually you would  use below pattern to flatten array - extract all array's elements into separate rows like in below example

```
WITH groc as (
  select ["ram", "abc", "xyz"] as list
) 
SELECT item || "2" item 
FROM groc,  UNNEST(list) item 
WHERE item != "xyz"
```

with output

[image]

You can read more about UNNEST function in respective [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest)